# How to root Samsung J3 2016 (SM-J320) without a computer

Tags: rooting, samsung

I have tried Kingo root,  Framroot and others, but  it wasn't possible to do it without a PC. How can I root it?

Comment: Please [edit] to mention Android Version. Answers could vary because these tools are exploits that may have been patched in subsequent versions

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly need a PC to do this - at least to get TWRP on it to be able to then flash Magisk, Xposed, etc afterwards. Refer to the [XDA page](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j3-2016) for the device, specifically [this TWRP and root guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j3-2016/how-to/guide-how-to-install-twrp-root-supersu-t3766822) I found by searching the forums.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for contributing to this website. May I, however, suggest you consider following [answer] so that to further improve your answers. Consider this post as an example. This is  a link dependent post. Its worth and usefulness depends on the life of the link. If the link dies, your answer would lose its value. We tend to invite answers which rely on themselves and use links wherever necessary. Please make sure to follow our referencing guide too in [help]. :)

Comment: @Firelord thanks will do, got a bit lazy answering on mobile